# Is there a way to make channels receive-only?

Tags: go

This clearly works:

```
// cast chan string to <-chan string
func RecOnly(c chan string) <-chan string {
    return c
}

func main() {
    a := make(chan string, 123)
    b := RecOnly(a)

    a <- "one"
    a <- "two"
    //b <- "beta" // compile error because of send to receive-only channel
    fmt.Println("a", <-a, "b", <-b)
}
```

but is there a one-liner to do this, without declaring a new function?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can explicitly define `b`'s type as a receive-only channel and set its value to `a`. You could also cast `a` to a receive-only channel. From the [Go spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Channel_types):

> A channel may be constrained only to send or only to receive by conversion or assignment.

```
func main() {
    a := make(chan string, 123)
    var b <-chan string = a // or, b := (<-chan string)(a)

    a <- "one"
    a <- "two"
    //b <- "beta" // compile error because of send to receive-only channel
    fmt.Println("a", <-a, "b", <-b)
}
```